# Given position by index and texture size, how can I calculate my hextiles position?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a hextiled map as show here:

http://files.slembcke.net/misc/procedural/hex_tiles.png

But I'm having some problems with my function converting the tiles X(row) and Y(column) index in a list to screen position:

```
        public static Vector2 GetDisplayCoordOfTile(GameTile t, Texture2D texture)
        {
            Vector2 screenPadding = new Vector2(2, 2);

            float ypos = (t.Column * (texture.Height + 2)) - (t.Row * texture.Height / (float)2) + screenPadding.Y;
            float xpos = (t.Row * (texture.Width)) + screenPadding.X;

            return new Vector2(xpos, ypos);
        }
```

Has anyone a clue where things go haywire, I cant make my mind wrap around the idea since the coordinatesystem diffs from thinking in regular arrays

Answer (score 0):

There's a great a tutorial on how to draw hexagonal maps here :
http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:TileEngineSeries:3

Also, you might get more help asking your game development related question here : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/